# does Euler's handshaking lemma apply to directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory

My textbook and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) both specify that Euler's handshaking lemma applies to undirected graphs. But it seem to work for directed as well. So why does it not apply to directed graphs?

Comment: It's just that it depends on how you define the degree of a vertex (out, in or both?).  The number of arcs in a digraph is the sum of outdegrees, which is equal to the sum of indegrees.  So the analog statement is that the number of edges is half the sum of out + in degrees.

Answer (score 2):

It does apply to directed graphs actually, but not in the way stated for undirected graphs. Because in directed graphs, we have **in-degree** and **out-degree** unlike a single degree definition in undirected graphs. But still, one can prove that
$$\sum_{v \in V(G)}d_{in}(v) = \sum_{v \in V(G)}d_{out}(v) = |E(G)|$$
Thus it still holds that
$$\sum_{v \in V(G)}\big(d_{in}(v)+d_{out}(v)\big) = 2|E(G)|$$
But I should also note that in directed graphs, we call what we call normally edge as **arc**. So, $|E(G)|$ is actually the number of arcs.